# How can we achieve hiddengrid functionality without caption layer programatically?

Tags: jqgrid

In our page, the grid will be inside an accordian. So i would like to eliminate the caption layer and implement the `hiddengrid:true` functionality on clicking on the accordian instead of clicking on the caption layer icon(in specific on opening of accordian). How can I achieve this? Any suggestions , thanks in advance.

The main intention is to have the functionality like in the documentation of `hiddengrid` option
`If set to true the grid is initially is hidden. The data is not loaded (no request is sent) and only the caption layer is shown. When the show/hide button is clicked for the first time to show grid, the request is sent to the server`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jQuery.slideUp](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/), [jQuery.slideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) or [jQuery.slideToggle](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) to implement the behavior close to `hiddengrid:true`.

To implement this you can place grid inside of a div like below

```html
<div id="overGrid">
    <table id="list"><tr><td></td></tr></table>
    <div id="pager"></div>
</div>
```

and use

```js
$("#overGrid").slideToggle("fast");
```

if you need to toggle the grid.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/TougleGridWithoutCapture.htm) demonstrate this.

**UPDATED**: Probably you have some remote `datatype` in the grid ("json" or "xml") and want don't load the grid contain at the beginning? In the case you need just use `datatype: "local"` initially and use `setGridParam` to change the datatype to `"json"` (or `"xml"`) inside of "select" callback of tab. After changing the datatype you should call `trigger("reloadGrd")` to load the data (or to refresh the data) from the server.

Comment: first let me say thanks for responding. I have updated the question to make it more clear. Here my intention is to send the request to server to load the data on some event, say on opening of the panel(or accordian).  And one more doubt  I have in the source code of the jqgrid is , in the line 11954, why they have disabled the selection (`$("tbody:first",$t).disableSelection();`) after calling `.sortable(opts)` though it is causing problem in inline editing. Could you please explain me what is the intention in that?

Comment: @venugopal: After the last editing I understand your question even less as before. Probably you have some remote `datatype` in the grid (`"json"` or `"xml"`) and want don't load the grid contain at the beginning? In the case you need just use `datatype: "local"` initially and use `setGridParam` to change the `datatype` to `"json"` (or `"xml"`) inside of "select" callback of tab. After changing the `datatype` you should call `trigger("reloadGrd")` to load the data (or to refresh the data) from the server.

Comment: Awesome ....Thank you very much oleg....its perfect. And could you please explain me why they disabled selection in `sortableRows()` function as it is making some problems in inline editing(ofcourse we can overcome them externally but i am keen to know why..)?

Comment: @venugopal: You are welcome! You should not ask *new question* in comments. The text of comments will be not used during searching on the stackoverflow. Moreover you should more clear explain the problem which you have. Do you know what `disableSelection` do and where it's defined? You should describe scenario where you have some problem with usage of `disableSelection` inside of `sortableRows` method. Moreover I don't understand at all which relation has with inline editing. You should just describe the problem exactly in new question.

Comment: sure sure, I follow your demos and I follow your suggestions :-) I will post a new question.